# Increment build number in bash

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, macos

I am trying to increment a build number by 1 using command line.

Here is the content of my test file:

```
SOME_DUMMY_VALUE = -1;
CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = 4;
SOME_SECOND_DUMMY_VALUE = -1;
CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = 4;
```

The result I want to obtain is the following:

```
SOME_DUMMY_VALUE = -1;
CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = 5;
SOME_SECOND_DUMMY_VALUE = -1;
CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = 5;
```

I am trying to use something like:

```
sed -i -E "s/CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = (\d+);/CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = \1~;/" test.txt
```

I am not experienced in bash scripting and I don't know how I can increment the number by one. (I am using MacOS but the sed command is almost the same as on Linux)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
awk -F '= ' '/CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION/{$2=$2+1";"}1' OFS='= ' input > output
```

Tests

```
cat file
SOME_DUMMY_VALUE = -1;
CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = 4;
SOME_SECOND_DUMMY_VALUE = -1;
CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = 4;

awk -F '= ' '/CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION/{$2=$2+1";"}1' OFS='= ' file
SOME_DUMMY_VALUE = -1;
CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = 5;
SOME_SECOND_DUMMY_VALUE = -1;
CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = 5;
```

Comment: I think that only the lines starting with `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION` are to be changed, so you may want to add a `$1 == "CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION"` condition to the first rule.

Comment: @AdminBee You are correct. Fixed my answer.

Comment: I think the `OFS='= ;'` statement is incorrect, look at the `;` appearing _in front of_ the incremented build number ...

Comment: @AdminBee Thank you 2 times!! ;)

Comment: All's well that ends well ;)

Answer (score 3):

Another answer, using only `awk`. This assumes that you adhere to the `key <space> = <space> value;` syntax throughout:

```
awk '$1 == "CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION" {$3=($3+1)";"}1' testfile.txt
```

This increases the third field by 1 in all lines starting with `CURRENT_PROJECT_NUMBER` but otherwise prints all lines "as is" (this is the meaning of the `1` behind the code block).

Note that I'm not sure if the "increment anything *starting* with a number" syntax is portable, so to be sure (and only slightly longer), we can remove the trailing semicolon from field 3 before incrementing:

```
awk '$1 == "CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION" {sub(";","",$3); $3=($3+1)";"}1' testfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

With sed and bash:

```
FILE="test.txt"
REGEX="\(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION *= *\)\([0-9]\+\);"

version=$(sed -ne "s/${REGEX}/\2/p" ${FILE} | head -1)
((version++))

sed -ie "s/${REGEX}/\1${version};/" ${FILE}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`, modifying the file in-place:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\bCURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION\s*=\s*\K-?\d+/$& + 1/ge' test.txt
```

Comment: Or perhaps more readable: `'s/\b(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION\s*=\s*)(-?\d+)/$1 . ($2+1)/e'`